# What Is The Lowest Temperature At Which A Fluid Will Flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

I’m studying Hydraulics, and this week we’re talking about viscosity and fluid properties and I came across this question but I can’t find the answer anywhere in my books. Please help.

Comment: What about the freezing point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of petroleum products, that temperature is called the *pour point*. It varies greatly, depending on the average molecular weight of the product- in general,  lower M.W. means a lower pour point temperature.

Comment: But then there is the pitch drop experiment. Less than a drop per year.

Comment: the petroleum community can't wait a year for a pour point determination ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe at 0K temperature and pressures below 25 atm, Helium will still be a fluid.

Comment: Indeed ... the question does not have a "reasonable" answer without knowing more about the properties of the fluid in question.